# Sending channel signal from a closure

Tags: rust, channel

I'm trying to send a signal from within a closure, using the following code.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    let t1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        watch(|x| tx.send(x));
    });

    let t2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    });

    let _ = t1.join();
    let _ = t2.join();
}

fn watch<F>(callback: F) where F : Fn(String) {
    callback("hello world".to_string());
}
```

However, it fails compiling raising the following error:

```
src/test.rs:8:19: 8:29 note: expected type `()`
src/test.rs:8:19: 8:29 note:    found type `std::result::Result<(), std::sync::mpsc::SendError<std::string::String>>`
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared that your `watch` function receives a closure of type `Fn(String)`. Usually a closure type includes its return type: `Fn(String) -> SomeReturnType`. `Fn(String)` is equivalent to `Fn(String) -> ()` and means that your closure should return an empty tuple `()`. `()` is often used similar to `void` in C.

However, the closure you're trying to use (`|x| tx.send(x)`) returns `std::result::Result<(), std::sync::mpsc::SendError<std::string::String>>` instead. You can use `unwrap()` on the `Result` to check that the operation have succeded and to make the closure return `()`:

```
watch(|x| tx.send(x).unwrap());
```

Alternatively, you can declare `watch` function in such way so it can receive a closure returning any type:

```
fn watch<F, R>(callback: F)
    where F: Fn(String) -> R
{
    // ...
}
```

But the `Result` should be checked anyway.