# Register multiple FFI callbacks with different function signatures

Tags: rust

I'm trying to code some bindings between Rust and a C dynamic library. With help of the Rust book, I'm able to link the dynamic library and call foreign functions.

My problem is that I have to register some callbacks to the C library but I'm not able to do it:

```
#[link(name = "MyLibrary")]
extern "C" {
    fn Auth_RegisterCallback(
        auth: size_t,
        name: *const c_char,
        function: &fn(size_t) -> i32,
        param: size_t,
    );
}

fn Authenticate() {
    unsafe {
        Auth_RegisterCallback(
            auth,
            CString::new("OnAuthBegin").unwrap().as_ptr(),
            OnAuthBegin,
            param,
        )
    };
    unsafe {
        NowAuth_RegisterCallback(
            auth,
            CString::new("OnSuccess").unwrap().as_ptr(),
            OnSuccess,
            param,
        )
    };
}

fn OnAuthBegin(auth: size_t) -> i32 {
    println!("Auth begin");
    return 1;
}
```

This code works fine because `Auth_RegisterCallback` in the extern block is expecting a function in parameter with one parameter of type `size_t`.

My problem is that I have multiple callbacks to register with different signatures like:

```
fn OnSuccess(context: size_t, success: size_t) -> i32 {
    println!("Success");
    return 1;
}
```

Is there a way to pass the functions in the parameters even though their signatures are different?

Comment: `CString::new("OnAuthBegin").unwrap().as_ptr()` — **please** read the documentation for `as_ptr` to understand why that will crash your app (also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48235267/155423).

Comment: `function: &fn(size_t) -> i32` — this is probably not what you want. This is a pointer to a function pointer. You probably just want `function: fn(size_t) -> i32`. Also it seems like it should be `extern "C" fn ...`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the definition of `NowAuth_RegisterCallback`? Do you wish to pass both `OnAuthBegin` and `OnSuccess` as the `function` argument? That doesn't make sense. The library is going to call the callback with a fixed number of arguments and if your function doesn't accept them, then memory will be corrupted. Does [How do I call a C function which returns many types of different function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45514870/155423) answer your question?

Comment: I'm sorry my question is unclear. Its hard to describe it. Actually, I do want to pass both OnAuth an OnSuccess to my C function because it's a generic function who takes *void as parameter: Auth_RegisterCallback(Auth* ctx, const char* name, void* func, void* param). After that it register the callback with the name and associate the function (Onauth or OnSuccess) with it.

Comment: Either represent that "generic" pointer as `*c_void` and use `transmute` or import it with different names and types and `#[link_name = "Auth_RegisterCallback"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your FFI takes an arbitrary pointer, that's what you have to denote your function as taking. Use `libc::c_void` and cast the function pointers:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_char, size_t, c_void};

use std::ffi::CString;

extern "C" {
    fn Auth_RegisterCallback(
        auth: size_t,
        name: *const c_char,
        function: *const c_void,
        param: size_t,
    );
}

fn authenticate() {
    let auth = unimplemented!();
    let param = unimplemented!();

    unsafe {
        Auth_RegisterCallback(
            auth,
            CString::new("OnAuthBegin").unwrap().into_raw(), // Memory leak
            on_auth_begin as *const _,
            param,
        );
        Auth_RegisterCallback(
            auth,
            CString::new("OnSuccess").unwrap().into_raw(), // Memory leak
            on_success as *const _,
            param,
        )
    };
}

fn on_auth_begin(auth: size_t) -> i32 {
    println!("Auth begin");
    return 1;
}

fn on_success(context: size_t, success: size_t) -> i32 {
    println!("Success");
    return 1;
}
```

You may wish to add *some* type safety by creating multiple individual wrappers around the FFI function:

```
fn register_begin_callback(f: fn(ctx: size_t, arg1: u8)) {
    let auth = unimplemented!();
    let param = unimplemented!();

    unsafe {
        Auth_RegisterCallback(
            auth,
            CString::new("OnAuthBegin").unwrap().into_raw(), // Memory leak
            f as *const _,
            param,
        );
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I call a C function which returns many types of different function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45514870/155423)

Comment: Also, after reading the Rust book [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ffi.html) I've realized that my callbacks are asynchronous and they are not triggered after being registered. I read that the async part of the callbacks with C is more complicated to implement because of the channels. I can't figure how to make this work with the channels and the threads. Can I use something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216185/sending-channel-signal-from-a-closure) ?